# Link without refresh in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link which open window.print after click. Is it possible to open page for print without refresh ? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="print-icon">
  <a title="Print" href="">Print page</a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.print-icon a').click(function(){
  window.print();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to your code:

```
$('.print-icon a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.print();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a hashtag in you `href`:

```
<div class="print-icon">
  <a title="Print" href="#">Print page</a>
</div>
```

---

Under the hood, a `href` starting with a hashtag directs the page to scroll to the `<a>` whose `name` attribute is equal to what's after it, for example:

```
<a name="toc"></a>
    some really long text
<a href="#toc"> Go to Table of Contents</a>
```

But by providing it with no anchor name (nothing after the `#`), there is nowhere to scroll to, so nothing happens, but styling is still applied.